# Align checkboxes within modal popup

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) which has been mostly painless. However, I just ran into the following problem when using inline checkboxes in a modal popup:

[image: checkbox not aligned]

The first row of the checkboxes are not aligned correctly.

Note that if I remove the inline property, this continues:
[image: checkbox not aligned when not inline]

The offending code is as follows:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="span4">

                <h4 style="display:inline !important;">Client: </h4> 

            </div>

            <div class="span4">

                <h4 style="display:inline !important;">Start Date: </h4> 

            </div>

            <div class="span4">

                <h4 style="display:inline !important;">End Date: </h4> 

            </div>

        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="span12">

                <h4 style="display:inline !important;">Industry: </h4> TBA

            </div>

        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="row-fluid">

            <h4>Role: </h4>

            <label class="checkbox inline">

                <input type="checkbox" value="2"> .NET Developer

            </label>

            <label class="checkbox inline">

                <input type="checkbox" value="1"> Business Analyst

            </label>

            <label class="checkbox inline">

                <input type="checkbox" value="14"> Change Manager

            </label>

            *SNIP*
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="span12">

                <h4>Scope of Work (max. 150 words): </h4>

                <textarea class="bdBox" rows="3"></textarea>

            </div>

        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="span12">

                <h4>Deliverables (max. 150 words): </h4>

                <textarea class="bdBox" rows="3"></textarea>

            </div>

        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Shortened for brevity.

Does anyone have any ideas on this, or should I take it to the Bootstrap issue list?

Comment: Hi shrodes,
I guess this is happening due to different width that individual checkboxes are having.
As I can see you have placed checkboxes inside label element, try giving a same fixed width to individual label element.
You can also try float:left instead of display:inline.....Just a guess.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.

There are two lines in the bootstrap.css file:

```
.radio.inline,.checkbox.inline{display:inline-block;padding-top:5px;margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle;}
.radio.inline+.radio.inline,.checkbox.inline+.checkbox.inline{margin-left:10px;}
```

The bottom line only applies the margin-left to checkboxes other than the first, meaning the first was not pushed across messing up the line.

If I move margin-left:10px into the first checkbox selector everything lines up. Mac's CSS was perfect for lining my checkboxes up too:
[image: Fixed checkboxes]

Comment: can you clarify what you mean?  Thanks.

Comment: @ming, don't know if this applies to later Bootstrap versions, but basically I put margin-left:10px into .radio.inline,.checkbox.inline selector.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I have tried and I suppose that is what you wanted

http://jsfiddle.net/xgKP4/

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty close to what I want, but the top row is still not aligned when I place it in the modal. 

I think there's a style in the modal ruining it, but I'm having trouble narrowing it down (it works fine on an isolated page, but not when I add it to the modal. See image: http://i.imgur.com/Hq6Hl.jpg)